# Any ffmpeg computing nodes out of there?

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding

Sadly I don't have access to powerful workstations and it happens that I have to convert lot of videos, however I do have an high bandwidth network.

Is there a free/paid computing cluster service where I can upload my ffmpeg command line and my videos and get them rendered/transcoded fastly by a cluster ?

Any workaround on this maybe with amazon or other services istances?

Comment: This might get better answers on superuser.

Comment: @stib Probably in SU I have to start explaining what is ffmpeg and that is not something edible :D

Comment: No, there are tons of ffmpeg questions on SU. FFMPEG is widely used on web servers - youTube uses it, for example. So there is probably already a solution that the web people will be able to point you to.